# ENTER traversal in Flutter

Tags: flutter

at Flutter I display TextField widget and IconButton widget in Table widget.

I need the cursor to move when the ENTER key is pressed
from the first field to the second field and so on to the last field a
then back to the first field and so on all the way around.

It is necessary that the cursor moves only between text fields,
not via the IconButton widget.

Do you know how to do it?

Thank you very much.

Example:
main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:traversal_fields/widgets/mytextfield.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const TraversalScreen());
}

class TraversalScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TraversalScreen({
    super.key,
  });


  @override
  State<TraversalScreen> createState() => _TraversalScreenState();
}

class _TraversalScreenState extends State<TraversalScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Traversal",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Traversal"),
        ),
        body: Table(
          columnWidths: const {
            0: FlexColumnWidth(3),
            1: FlexColumnWidth(3),
            3: FlexColumnWidth(3),
            4: FlexColumnWidth(3),
          },
          border: TableBorder(
            horizontalInside: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor),
          ),
          children: [
            myTableRow(),
            myTableRow(),
            myTableRow(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  TableRow myTableRow() {
    return TableRow(
      children: [
        const TableCell(
          child: MyTextField(),
        ),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print("Click Icon Button");
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.link),
        ),
        const TableCell(
          child: MyTextField(),
        ),
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print("Click Icon Button");
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.link),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

mytextfield.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTextField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyTextField> createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<MyTextField> {
  final TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myController.addListener(_printLatestValue);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _printLatestValue() {
    print('Second text field: ${myController.text}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        hintText: 'Enter a text',
      ),
      controller: myController,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `textInputAction: TextInputAction.next` in `TextField()` widget.